# vs code extension command run detail

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

how could I check the vscode extension command's run details? for example, I installed PlantUML extension and on right click there is one relative command "Export Current Diagram", how could I trace this command and check it's executable process detail?

Answer (score 0):

maybe the extension provides an output channel `vscode.window.createOutputChannel`?  The output channels are listed in the output tab of the panel that includes the integrated terminal. A good example being the output channel that the `Git` extension provides.

It is the responsibility of the extension to log info about its own execution.

Comment: it provides  vscode.window.createOutputChannel, but it only appends execution result, without any execution details. maybe another question about How to debug Visual Studio Code extensions? may be helpful,  but I didn't  go deep and just create a new task to replace this command, thanks anyway.